# Highslide: fullscreen not working in an iframe

Tags: flash, iframe, fullscreen, away3d, highslide

I'm building a website under wordpress and I'm using highslide to diplay a flash video player in an iframe.

This player can normally go fullscreen by clicking a dedicated button but since it's developped in Away3D the fullscreen is not working with Google Chrome (known bug): it's going blank.

That's why I had to use a script on the page loading the player to go fullscreen through google fullscreen API.

You can see examples on the following test site (that I made up just for you since I'm working offline for now):

http://ipgtest.co.nf

- The first ipad image just loads a classic highslide: it's working perfectly.
- The second ipad image loads the flash player loader page alone and you'll see that the fullscreen button (arrow) on the player works perfectly on google chrome and every other browser.
- The third ipad image loads the flash player loader page in an iframe in highslide and you'll see that the fullscreen button doesn't work at all on Google Chrome...

feel free to read the source code of http://ipgtest.co.nf/play/index.html to see how the chrome fullscreen is taken care normally.

Tanks a lot for your help, I really despear to find a solution...

Julien

Comment: Are you sure the script you are using to allow fullscreen in Google Chrome is meant to work inside an iframe? I get the same result with the fullscreen button in Chrome in the Highslide iframe popup as I do when I put your page in a regular iframe: `<iframe src="http://ipgtest.co.nf/play/index.html" width="765" height="546"></iframe>`

Comment: Well you're right, I'm using THREEx and it is not working in an iframe but there's a trick by adding "allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen width="xxx" height="yyy" frameborder="0">" on a normal iframe, I added one test iframe (you can see it on the site) and it's working inside the iframe but it's still not working inside Highslide because the iframe is not called the same way... I don't know how to include the additionnal scipts to allow fullscreen... Do you have any clue ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Juliens latest comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285073/highslide-fullscreen-not-working-in-an-iframe?noredirect=1#comment21584513_15285073) above with info about a trick by adding `allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen` to the code for the iframe, the only solution is to add the same code to the code that creates the iframe in the highslide-full.js file (or the highslide-with-html.js file - it depends of which Highslide file you’re using).

Open the Highslide js file in a text editor (not Word or similar) and find this line: 
*(line 1668 in highslide-full.js - line 1435 in highslide-with-html.js / both version 4.1.13, the line number might change in later versions)*

```
this.body.innerHTML += '<iframe name="hs'+ (new Date()).getTime() +'" frameborder="0" key="'+ this.key +'" '
```

Change the line to this:

```
this.body.innerHTML += '<iframe allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen name="hs'+ (new Date()).getTime() +'" frameborder="0" key="'+ this.key +'" '
```